# Rails - 3 nested models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, models

I'm struggling with grasping the fundamentals behind writing model methods, which is I think what I need to do to get this to work. Basically, I have a project view that's showing project_todos that belong to that project. Then nested under that I have project_todo_comments that belong to a project_todo. All in one view.

I've set up the associations so that project `has_many` project_todos, project_todo `belongs_to` project and `has_many` project_todo_comments. Then of course project_todo_comment `belongs_to` project_todo.

In the projects controller, I'm doing this:

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    # Display the form to create a new todo
    @project_todo = ProjectTodo.new

    # Create the instance variable to display the loop in the view
    @todos = @project.project_todos

    # Display the form to create a new comment
    @project_todo_comment = ProjectTodoComment.new

     # Create the instance variable to display the loop in the view
    @comments = @project.project_todo_comments

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @project }
    end
  end
```

So this is working to the point where I can add todos on a project and display them, and I can also add comments to project todos and display them too, all in that same view. BUT, I'm having difficulties getting the comments to display ONLY with the todos that they're associated with. Right now, when I add a comment on any todo, every single todo then displays that comment.

In the view, here's where I'm displaying the project_todos and nesting the form to add a comment, then displaying the comments:

```
 <% @todos.each do |todo| %>
    <p><%= todo.title %></p>

    <%= form_for(@project_todo_comment) do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :project_todo_id, :value => @project_todo.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
        <%= f.text_area :comment %>
        <%= f.submit 'Add Comment' %>
    <% end %>

    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= comment.comment %>
    <% end %>

  <% end %>
```

I've been told that I need to write a model method to get this to work, but I'm still trying to understand those. Could anyone just reassure that I do in fact need to write a model method, and point me in a direction to learn about them? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you get all of the comments, but in an actual `todo` item you just want the comments for that item. This can be done with: `todo.project_todo_comments`
The easiest way to solve:

```
- <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
-   <%= comment.comment %>
- <% end %>

+ <% todo.project_todo_comments.each do |comment| %>
+   <%= comment.comment %>
+ <% end %>
```

You can remove the line from your controller:

```
- @comments = @project.project_todo_comments
```

However in your form (where you create a comment) you use the wrong ID for the todo item:

```
- <%= f.hidden_field :project_todo_id, :value => @project_todo.id %>
+ <%= f.hidden_field :project_todo_id, :value => todo.id %>
```

By the way, I would just name those models:
`Todo` and `Comment`, there is no point using that long modelnames. You define those associations in the start of your model, so if someone would read it, he/she would see it instantly.

For example see myself, I knew what was the purpose of your models still misused the namings, cause of too long classnames.

Comment: But then comments is undefined. Should it be ```<% todo.project_todo_comments.each do |comment| %>``` instead?

Comment: Ye right, I corrected my answer, i was bugged cause those class names are a bit long.

Comment: Hmm okay. So I don't get any errors when doing that, but the comments are now not displaying at all, even when I add a new todo and new comments. I guess I don't understand how this is working when you take out the ```@comments``` instance variable from the controller. How is it accessing the model now? Is it solely because of the has_many belongs_to association?

Comment: So you iterate @todos with `each` method, and there you got a `todo` item. You can use object methods in you views as well (however try to keep it minimal for keeping MVC style). So basically you need to use this `todo` item as well in your form to really join the comment for that item. ( updated my answer )

Comment: Awesome, that makes sense and it works! Thanks. BUT I still don't get how we can do ```todo.project_todo_comments``` without having an instance variable in the controller that lets you access the project_todo_comments model.

Comment: With `<% @todos.each do |todo| %>` you create a local variable `todo` which you can use as a normal model instance ( like it would be created in the controller as an instance variable )

Comment: Okay that's sort of making sense. So could I do the same thing for looping through the project todos? Like instead of using ```<% @todos.each do |todo| %>``` I would use ```<% project.project_todos.each do |todo| %>```? I'm just not understanding why we're doing something differently for the comments but not the todos. Am I making any sense?

Comment: Ofc. To see the big picture, its just namespacing and stuff, you can do everything what you want if you include the necessary classes/methods, HOWEVER its not recommended cause it hurts the MVC principle. Just to be clear what u wrote in your previous comment is totally okay, does not hurt the MVC.

Comment: Gottcha. Your method for looping through comments was just a different way than I used to loop through todos. I've changed it now so that they're both using your method. And I got to remove a line from my controller too so that's good. Thanks for your help!